# Programmatically generated text field is not showing up in Android app

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to programmatically generate some UI elements onto an android app with Java. I have a ScrollView created in the XML file, and I'm trying to create and add a bunch of UI elements to that ScrollView. All of the UI elements make up 1 bounding box that looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/pwI8MNi.jpg]

The bounding box is just a linear layout with an image background, and some text boxes and labels sitting on top of it. I want my code to be modular, so I'm making a class called BoundingBox which should create and add a bounding box to the app every time I instantiate the BoundingBox class.

Here's what I have so far for the BoundingBox class (it's not complete, all it adds so far is a textview with text on it).

```
public class BoundingBox {
//Instantiate the main app activity.
MainActivity theMainActivity = new MainActivity();

//Create Scrollview object and set it to the XML GUI scrollview
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) theMainActivity.findViewById(R.id.theMainScrollView);

public BoundingBox(){

    //Create linear layout that will sit in the scrollview.
    LinearLayout mainLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(theMainActivity);

    TextView exerciseName = new TextView(theMainActivity);

    TextView repBox1 = new TextView(theMainActivity);
    TextView repBox2 = new TextView(theMainActivity);
    TextView repBox3 = new TextView(theMainActivity);
    TextView repBox4 = new TextView(theMainActivity);


    //Add the Linear Layout to the existing scroll view.

    sv.addView(mainLinearLayout);

    //Add text box to linear layout
    mainLinearLayout.addView(exerciseName);
    exerciseName.setText("This doesn't work.");

    }
}
```

Here's how I instantiate it in my main Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    BoundingBox sc = new BoundingBox();
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return true;
}
```

The code compiles successfully but no text shows up in my Android app. If I instantiated the class then it should have already ran the code in the BoundingBox constructor, which should have created a text view. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and since the code compiles successfully logcat doesn't tell me anything. If I instantiate the bounding box class in the onCreate() function, the app crashes when starting it. If I instantiate it in the onCreateOptionsMenu function, it runs but it doesn't create a text view.

Comment: `MainActivity theMainActivity = new MainActivity();` this is very bad.

Comment: is running only because onCreateOptionsMenu is not being invoked

Comment: How is it bad? What do I need to do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is so messed up it isn't even close to working.

1)You should never create an activity via new.  Ever.  It isn't valid.

2)You create a LinearLayout programmatically.  But you add it nowhere.  If it isn't added to anywhere, where would you expect it to show?

3)Why would you ever want to create a view in options menu code?  And once again, you're creating the box but not doing anything with the views it creates.  Also, if you want to create a class that holds a bunch of views, it really ought to derive from ViewGroup.

4)Even if 1 was valid (it isn't), doign a findViewById there would return null, because onCreate wasn't called so no contentView was set.  But that isn't valid anyway, so don't try to just call it.  Instead you want to either pass in the parent view via constructor, or better yet make BoundingBox a ViewGroup subclass and add it to the parent directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, at least I know now that I'm doing everything wrong. I'm pretty new to this sort of thing. I will review the Android API and see if I can better understand how to create a new view.

Comment: 2) He adds it to the `ScrollView` 'sv'.  Right ?

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought I was doing.

Comment: Except that sv will never be valid

Comment: So I think I fixed this, please tell me if this is a terrible way to do this: I extended LinearLayout in the BoundingBox class, and then I just added that to the Scrollview that is defined after the setContentView() method. The code finally runs without any crashing, and the text label appears.